# What should I say after "than" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> One of the benefits of choosing to conduct a predictive validity study
>   is the greater likelihood of having  more qualified and productive
>   employees than ____.

After *than* should it be

A. concurrent validity study.

B. there is with concurrent validity study.

C. if concurrent validity study were to be chosen.

Those are my choices, if you know a better one, please tell me.

Comment: Is this a question from an exam? Is it homework? Please provide some context. None of your choices are grammatically correct, and without context, there are an infinite number of possible revisions. You have asked 76 questions, so by now you must know that _"if you know a better one, please tell me"_ is asking us to proofread!

Comment: No. This is my sentence. I am writing for a group project paper. I was writing and then I kept changing the wording after than until I just got very confused that I came here to ask.

Comment: The same thing is wrong with every one of your choices. Read them closely to see if you can figure out what is missing.

Comment: I don't know. If I were to say this differently. "There is greater likelihood of something happening in X than there is with Y." Isn't this correct?

Comment: The omission is very basic. The same thing, the same part of speech, is missing from each of your options.

Comment: I really don't know what it is that is missing.

Comment: Try reading this and see if you can tell what is missing: **One of the benefits of choosing to conduct a predictive validity study is the greater likelihood of having more qualified and productive employees than concurrent validity study.** (p.s. The answer below does not address this error.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46911/discussion-between-ghaith-alrestom-and-p-e-dant).

Answer (score 1):

The options you listed lack *[parallel structure](http://www.evergreen.edu/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf)*. The following fixes this problem:

> One of the benefits of choosing to conduct a predictive validity study is the greater likelihood of having more qualified and productive employees *than if one were to choose a* *[enter alternative option here].*